# How to find a object with higher number in name?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In Resources folder I have some prefabs what have names with numbers 2,3,4... and I want to load the object with higher number always when player click the button. Now I'm using a that code to load prefabs with one name.

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate(

    Resources.Load("Cubes2", typeof(GameObject))

) as GameObject;
```

How can I change this code to load prefab with other number or higher number than last loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would set an int **myNum** and increment it from somewhere in your code, it could work like this..

```
GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Cubes" + myNum, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
```

Result would be "Cubes2"